# My computer works fine without the Ethernet cable but as soon as I plug the cable in, it is extremely slow

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet, windows-server-2012-r2

So, this is a weird one. The network I control, had a power blip in the morning and right after that, there were issues. As soon as the users log in to their computers, it would take extreme amount of time on the "Welcome" screen and then all they would see is a black screen with a cursor. After waiting for a good 30-40 minutes, they would see their desktop. And if they try to open any application or even their Windows Explorer window, it would freeze on them. The same thing happens on DC and Fileserver.

All the computers are Windows 10 and the servers are Windows 2012 R2.

If I disconnect the Ethernet cable, there are no issues and the computer functions normally (without the Internet connection) but as soon as I plug the cable in, the performance slows down by like 90-95%, which leads me to believe that there could be network congestion.

The users do have roaming profiles but none of them are large enough to take extreme amount of login time. Before the blip, it barely took them a minute or two (each) and after the blip, it takes about 25 minutes.

We have fiber at the location so Internet speed is not an issue.

Can anyone shed some light on something that we may have missed? Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Are you using roaming profiles? If you suspect network congestion, how much traffic do you see on the network? Have you tried rebooting all Ethernet switches? (Some devices just don't react well to brownouts; I had switches start corrupting packets when that happens.)

Comment: I have actually not restarted the switches. I have done computers, routers and servers but not switches.